# Multiplying last row of the matrix with a variable of different order

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to multiply just last row of a matrix with a variable of different order;

```
%A matrix
          N = length(a)-1;% order of the matrix
           last_row = (a(1:end-1))*(1/a(end));% creating the last row
          k = ones(1,N-1);
          A = diag(k,1) ; % diag(vector, k) produce a matrix filled with zero's and k'th off diagonal as vector, in this  case, 1's.
           last_row = (wc.^(N:-1:1)).*last_row;% multiply the variable with different order.
           A(end,:) = last_row;% adding the last_row
```

before i multiply the variables to my "last_row"

```
last_row =
      1.0000    2.6131    3.4142    2.6131
```

my matrix :

```
A =
       0     1     0     0
       0     0     1     0
       0     0     0     1
       0     0     0     0
```

after multiplying the variable:

```
last_row =
    1.0e+009 *
      1.2624    0.0175    0.0001    0.0000
```

when i insert the last row:

```
A =
    1.0e+009 *
           0    0.0000         0         0
           0         0    0.0000         0
           0         0         0    0.0000
      1.2624    0.0175    0.0001    0.0000
```

It is changing elements which isn't my last_row, where am i going wrong. All those 1's should remain as it is

Comment: You mean for example A(1,2) should be one? Then I have to tell you it *still* is 1 ! Matlab tries to format the matrix to account for the last row. Just check for your self if A(1,2 ) is 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your calculations are correct, only the last row of the resulting matrix is changed. MATLAB tries to account for all numbers of a matrix when it is formatting it for output.
So in short there is no problem. For example check if A(1,2) is 1
If you want different formatting, take a look at `format` or `sprintf`

Comment: Ok so this is totally useless post, sorry about that

Comment: Did you check A(1,2)?

Comment: Yes, it was 1. No sure how to change formatting though

Comment: Then can you tell me why you said something like **totally useless post**??

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator: they are apologising for their question.